# iPhone - UINavigationItem ignored when loading View Controller from xib

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a `UIViewController` within a `UINavigationController`, and I'm pushing a second `UIViewController` onto the navigation stack from a XIB file. This XIB also includes a `UINavigationItem` for the second view controller's title and button, but these are ignored when loading the XIB. Any ideas?

Here is my code (photoViewController is the second viewController)

```
- (void) displayPhotoWithId:(int)photoId {

    if (_photoViewController == nil) {
        self.photoViewController = [[[PhotoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PhotoView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];        
    }

    _photoViewController.photoId = photoId;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_photoViewController animated:YES]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation item is ignored because it has nothing to do with this controller, it's just happened to be in this controller's XIB. Controller's navigation item is created on instantiation. You have to setup title and navigation buttons in code (in `viewDidLoad` for example) because controller doesn't have `navigationItem` outlet. UINavigationItem in XIB works only inside UINavigationController's root controller.

Comment: Thanks hoha. So there's no way to use a UINavigationItem from Interface Builder here?

Comment: There isn't I'm afraid. It has something to do with order of view loading in controller. I forgot what it was, but now UINavigationItem just doesn't work from XIBs.

Answer (score 3):

You can wire this up from interface builder. Add something like this to your view controller:

```
IBOutlet UINavigationItem* navigationItem;
```

Then wire it up to the view controller outlets (from File Owner, presumably, to the `UINavigationItem` in your XIB). I have done this and it works fine. I suppose `UINavigationController` looks for the 'navigationItem' automagically.

Comment: This will work, if your controller's view is loaded before you add it to the UINavigationController.

Comment: Agreed with Sulthan - so if your root controller loads it's navigationItem from a XIB, it will crash. Recommend using Storyboards or doing it in code.